# Google Rich Results Test - Item does not support reviews

Tags: seo, metadata, google-search-console, json-ld

I was trying out a bunch of things on Google's Rich Results Test, and ran into this issue.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test SEO</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
       "@context":"https://schema.org",
       "@type":"Service",
       "name":"ABC",
       "aggregateRating":{
          "@type":"AggregateRating",
          "ratingValue":5,
          "reviewCount":2
       },
       "review":[
          {
             "@type":"Review",
            "name": "ABC",
             "author": {
               "@type": "Person",
               "name": "David A"
             },
             "reviewBody":"Awesome",
             "reviewRating":{
                "@type":"Rating",
                "ratingValue":5
             }
          },
          {
             "@type":"Review",
            "name": "ABC",
             "author": {
               "@type": "Person",
               "name": "David B"
             },
             "reviewBody":"Great",
             "reviewRating":{
                "@type":"Rating",
                "ratingValue":5
             }
          }
       ]
    }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I ran the test, it returned 3 errors, 2 of them saying

> Item does not support reviews

and 1 of them saying

> Invalid object type for field 'itemReviewed'

For the first error, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error as I provided all the required fields for a `review` (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#review-properties).

As for the second error, again I think I provided all the needed fields according to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#aggregated-rating-type-definition, but still getting back that error.

I didn't provide `itemReviewed` to either objects, since the document indicated if it's nested, it can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best answer I found was this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/38450143/doubts-about-service-schema?hl=en

It seems like even though [Schema.org](https://schema.org/Service) supports `Service`, it's not part of the schema type that is supported by Google by the looks of it (https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful).

As a reference, [this is an example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#embedded-review-example) from their docs, and if you change the `@type` from `Product` to `Service`, you will see similar errors pop up.

I guess the solution here is to update from `Service` to `Product`, but it's just a bit weird considering how GSC(Google Search Console) didn't spit out warnings until now...